# Animation not working in iOS8

Tags: ios

Animation is not working in iOS8 but is working well in iOS7. May I know how to solve this problem?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ever the code I am using for iOS7 the same code I am using for iOS8 and its working fine.
There is no change for doing animations in iOS8. You can use below code to do animations.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
 self.dropdownTable.frame=CGRectMake(419, 184, 606, 331);
 }];
```

Comment: it working after change from setframe to .frame. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Animation with block works well both in iOS7 and iOS8.
For more information you should go in your xcode project to UIKit.framework. Then you should find UIView.h class. There you find:

```
@interface UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks)

+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);

+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0); // delay = 0.0, options = 0

+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0); // delay = 0.0, options = 0, completion = NULL

/* Performs `animations` using a timing curve described by the motion of a spring. When `dampingRatio` is 1, the animation will smoothly decelerate to its final model values without oscillating. Damping ratios less than 1 will oscillate more and more before coming to a complete stop. You can use the initial spring velocity to specify how fast the object at the end of the simulated spring was moving before it was attached. It's a unit coordinate system, where 1 is defined as travelling the total animation distance in a second. So if you're changing an object's position by 200pt in this animation, and you want the animation to behave as if the object was moving at 100pt/s before the animation started, you'd pass 0.5. You'll typically want to pass 0 for the velocity. */

+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay usingSpringWithDamping:(CGFloat)dampingRatio initialSpringVelocity:(CGFloat)velocity options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

+ (void)transitionWithView:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);

+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0); // toView added to fromView.superview, fromView removed from its superview

/* Performs the requested system-provided animation on one or more views. Specify addtional animations in the parallelAnimations block. These additional animations will run alongside the system animation with the same timing and duration that the system animation defines/inherits. Additional animations should not modify properties of the view on which the system animation is being performed. Not all system animations honor all available options.
 */

+ (void)performSystemAnimation:(UISystemAnimation)animation onViews:(NSArray *)views options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))parallelAnimations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

@end
```

It should help you. Also don't forget to change UIViewGeometry in order to make animation.
For example:

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.f, 20.f, 50.f, 50.f)];

    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [self.view addSubview:testView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f animations:^{
        testView.center = self.view.center;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Complete = %d", finished);
    }];
```

Also you can change color, alpha in block of animation (and other properties of UIView).